# Django TestCase DB missing columns that are in the DB when I runserver

Tags: django, django-unittest

When I start my app it works perfectly, but when I try to run a testcase it creates the test DB from my local copy and errors for a missing column that I can see in my local DB and was part of an older migrations.

Any suggestions

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\mtmcd\Azure Devops\Blindspot> python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8888
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 19, 2022 - 11:02:25
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'blindspot.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8888/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[19/May/2022 11:02:48] "GET /endpoints/list HTTP/1.1" 200 82572
```

But when I run python manage.py test I get

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\mtmcd\Azure Devops\Blindspot> python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mtmcd\Azure Devops\Blindspot\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column agents_simulationaction.alert_test_name does not exist
LINE 1: ...d", "agents_simulationaction"."security_tool_id", "agents_si...
```

Comment: there are two options: 1) u are still referring to that column inside the code or more probably, 2) the migration is broken, which means that u didn't follow the best patterns for creating the migration files. To make a test, just let Django refer to a new db and try to apply the migrations from scratch and let us know if it works

Comment: First, Delete the test DB and then try again. If that not works your migrations are broken. Then you need to roll back migrations and overwrite the broken one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by doing the following.

Deleting all migrations, doing a makemigrations, deleting the entries in the django_migrations table, then migrate --fake on the main DB. This allowed the test DB to create successfully